# Rails nested where clause on join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two models with associations through a join table. Here is the schema...

```
  create_table "group_shots", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "shot_id"
    t.integer  "group_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end

  create_table "groups", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end

  create_table "shots", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "comedian_id"
    t.string   "pic_file_name"
    t.string   "pic_content_type"
```

In my groups controller I'm trying to do something like...

```
 def show
    @group = Group.find(params[:id])
    @shots = Shot.where(GroupShot.where(:group_id => @group.id))
```

I am getting the error "Cannot visit ActiveRecord::Relation". What is the right way to do this? I'm using Rails 3.2

## EDIT

...my models are...

```
#app/models/group_shot.rb
class GroupShot < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :shots
  belongs_to :groups
  attr_accessible :group_id, :shot_id

#app/models/group.rb
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :shots, through: :group_shot
  attr_accessible :name
end

#app/models/shot.rb
class Shot < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :groups, :through => :group_shot
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have your group model set up like:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :group_shots
  has_many :shots, through: :group_shots
end

class Shot < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :group_shots
  has_many :groups, :through => :group_shots
end

class GroupShot < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :shot
  belongs_to :group
end
```

Then you can do something like

```
@shots = @group.shots
```

Comment: Hmm...still not working. I added my model associations above. Please sanity check those for me. Thanx!

Comment: I updated my original comment.  When you use :belongs_to you need to use the singular spelling of the model, and :has_many will be plural.

I also forgot to add the has_many :group_shots relations.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Smack! That was TJ bitch slapping active record associations. Thanks bud!

Answer (score 1):

If the "associations through" is configured right:

```
@group = Group.find(params[:id])
@shots = @group.shots
```